# Bot Framework: Adaptive Cards Capabilities across Channels | Carousel | Input | Action Buttons

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

I was going through the documentation for adaptive cards, and I had a few queries:

There are certain capabilities that I am looking to target through Adaptive Cards, across channels (Webchat, Bing, Skype, Facebook Messenger). These include:

```
Showing a carousel of cards within the platform
Taking input from user within the card to provide an input/edit experience . 
Action buttons as part of card, to perform an action (e.g. opening a webpage) when clicked.
```

I believe that most of these actions are available for Webchat, Bing, Skype, Microsoft Teams. Is there a way to accomplish this for channels like Facebook and Kik using adaptive cards? What is the level of customization required from the same?
Also, is Carousel supported across channels?

Thank you for the help!.

Comment: https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/channel-inspector/channels/Slack/

You can use this tool to view how the UI components being rendered in specific channel

Comment: I was looking to target these functionalities using adaptive cards (e.g. carousel of adaptive cards, buttons and input actions using these cards) to keep the functionality as channel agnostic as possible. Is it possible to achieve these using them?

Comment: adaptive card is quite new, even *web chat* which is developed by Microsoft doesn't support it fully yet (still in **PR**). I think you should not use it for production

Answer (score 1):

For the Carousel question, see @kienct89 comment: you have samples of Carousel display in `https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/channel-inspector/channels/Facebook?f=Carousel&e=example1`.

For the Adaptive cards, see the `Visualizer` on http://adaptivecards.io/visualizer/ and you will face the problem that taking input is not supported for Facebook and Kik for example (only Bing and Webchat have the possibility for input in their sample).